# Why does swagger codegen generates createAll java method name as create_all_using_postIntValue in python instead of create_all_using_post?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

While generating swagger client through CodeGen, it is appending 2 digits character at the end of the method name. For Ex: Java rest API
**HTTP POST /all**
is generating the method name in python client as
**create_all_using_postIntValue** or **create_all_using_post19**

I want the generated method name as create_all_using_post. Why is it happened and how to fix this?

I am using below commands to generate the client:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i https://example.com/v3/api-docs -l python -o swagger_test
```

Comment: Can you post your OpenAPI definition? It probably happens because the operations don't have `operationId`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. MethodName can be override by implementing OperationBuilderPlugin. Below code fixed my issue:

```
import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import springfox.documentation.service.Operation;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.OperationBuilderPlugin;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.OperationContext;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.common.SwaggerPluginSupport;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 1000)
public class GenerateUniqueOperationName implements OperationBuilderPlugin {

@Override
public void apply(OperationContext context) {
    Optional<ApiOperation> methodAnnotation = context.findControllerAnnotation(ApiOperation.class);
    Operation operationBuilder = context.operationBuilder().build();

    if(operationBuilder.getTags().stream().findFirst().get().isEmpty())
        throw new RuntimeException("operationBuilder.getTags().stream().findFirst()");

    String tag = operationBuilder.getTags().stream().findFirst().get();
    String methodType =  operationBuilder.getMethod().name().toUpperCase();
    String methodName = operationBuilder.getSummary();

    String operationId = tag + "_" + methodType + "_" + CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, methodName);

    context.operationBuilder().uniqueId(operationId);
    context.operationBuilder().codegenMethodNameStem(operationId);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
    return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
}
```

}